# Optimizing the SQL Query to get data from large amount MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I am having a problem getting data from a large amount MySQL database.

With the below code it is ok to get the list of 10K patients and 5K appointments which is our test server.

However, on our live server, the number of patients is over 100K and the number of appointments is over 300K and when I run the code after a while it gives 500 error.

I need the list of the patients whose patient_treatment_status is 1 or 3 and has no appointment after one month from their last appointment. (The below code is working for small amount of patients and appointments)

How can I optimise the first database query so there will be no need the second database query in the foreach loop?

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

require_once('Db.class.php');

$patients = $db->query("
SELECT
    p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.phone, p.mobile,
    LatestApp.lastAppDate
FROM
    patients p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT patient_id, MAX(start_date) AS lastAppDate FROM appointments WHERE appointment_status = 4) LatestApp ON p.id = LatestApp.patient_id
WHERE
    p.patient_treatment_status = 1 OR p.patient_treatment_status = 3
ORDER BY
    p.id
");

foreach ($patients as $row) {
    $one_month_after_the_last_appointment = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['lastAppDate'] . " +1 month"));
    $appointment_check = $db->single("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM appointments WHERE patient_id = :pid AND appointment_status = :a0 AND (start_date >= :a1 AND start_date <= :a2)", array("pid"=>"{$row['id']}","a0"=>"1","a1"=>"{$row['lastAppDate']}","a2"=>"$one_month_after_the_last_appointment"));

    if($appointment_check == 0){
        echo $patient_id = $row['id'].' - '.$row['lastAppDate'].' - '.$one_month_after_the_last_appointment. '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If it was me, I’d get rid of all the php for now and instead focus on the sql. If you agree, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Ideally you should not be running two queries - especially the one in the loop.

Comment: I think the speed problem is relative to the subquery and the LEFT JOIN. I think it is better for you to use a INNER JOIN to speed up the query, remove your subquery, normal JOINING the other table, and use a group by appointment id (if any) and in the select using MAX to get the latest appointment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this subquery likely does not do what you think it does.

```
SELECT patient_id, MAX(start_date) AS lastAppDate 
FROM appointments WHERE appointment_status = 4
```

Without a GROUP BY clause, that subquery will simply take the maximum `start_date` of all appointments with `appointment_status=4`, and then arbitrarily pick one `patient_id`. To get the results you want you'll need to `GROUP BY patient_id`.

For your overall question, try the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.phone, p.mobile,
    LatestApp.lastAppDate
FROM
    patients p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT patient_id,
    MAX(start_date) AS lastAppDate
    FROM appointments
    WHERE appointment_status = 4
    GROUP BY patient_id
) LatestApp ON p.id = LatestApp.patient_id
WHERE
    (p.patient_treatment_status = 1
    OR p.patient_treatment_status = 3)
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM appointments a
        WHERE a.patient_id = p.patient_id
        AND a.appointment_status = 1
        AND a.start_date >= LatestApp.lastAppDate
        AND a.start_date < DATE_ADD(LatestApp.lastAppDate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
)
ORDER BY
    p.id
```

Add the following index, if it doesn't already exist:

```
ALTER TABLE appointments
ADD INDEX (`patient_id`, `appointment_status`, `start_date`)
```

Report how this performs and if the data appears correct. Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE patient` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE appointments` for further assistance related to performance.

Also, try the query above without the `AND NOT EXISTS` clause, together with the second query you use. It is possible that running 2 queries may be faster than trying to run them together, in this situation.

Note that I used an `INNER JOIN` to find the latest appointment. This will result in all patients that have never had an appointment to not be included in the query. If you need those added, just UNION the results those found by selecting from patients that have never had an appointment.

Comment: @RickJames Are you sure you didn't overlook the fact that I added `GROUP BY patient_id` to that derived table? Otherwise, I would agree with you.

Comment: Oops; corrected advice for first derived table:  `INDEX(appointment_status, patient_id, start_date)`.